# Laravel - Return polymorphic relation grouped

Tags: laravel, group-by, polymorphism

I have a polymorphic relation :

```
Fields :
value
type
fieldable_id
fieldable_type


Customer :
id
name
...
```

I can acces my fields with $customer->fields

But I want to get my fields grouped by type like this :

```
phone => [Object Field]
         [Object Field 2]
email => [Object Field 3]
         [Object Field 4]
```

How can I do it?

I try with `groupBy` but it has merged all of it into one and I have lost the others

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know why but it works now with `$customer->fields->groupBy('type');`